# Site is not loading Post From Sql. It is showing zero Post

Tags: php, sql, pdo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60aeZ.png)   Code was working in 2017 Now I again upload in my cpanel not post is not showing.Site is not loading Post From Sql. It is showing zero Post. I think it is due to old version of sql?

```
<?php

        // how many records should be displayed on a page?
        $records_per_page = 4;

        // include the pagination class
        require 'classes/Pagination.php';

        // instantiate the pagination object
        $pagination = new Pagination();

        // the MySQL statement to fetch the rows

        $MySQL = 'SELECT Table * FROM covers ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT
                ' . (($pagination->get_page() - 1) * $records_per_page) . ', ' . $records_per_page . '
        ';

        // if query could not be executed
        $result = $db->query($MySQL);

        // fetch the total number of records in the table
        $myRows = $db->query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS rows');
        $rows = $myRows->fetch();

        // pass the total number of records to the pagination class
        $pagination->records($rows['rows']);

        // records per page
        $pagination->records_per_page($records_per_page);

        $page = $pagination->get_page();

        ?><div class="row">
            <?php 
            $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $index = 1;
            $begin = ($page * $records_per_page) - $records_per_page;

                    if ($result->rowCount() == 0) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>There are no covers.</div>";
        }else{
            foreach($rows as $row) {
            ?>
```

Comment: You need to do some debugging. Check the web servers error log and check if that gives you any clues. Currently, it's quite impossible for us to know what's going on. Specially since you say the code use to work. That suggests that there are some dependencies (php-extension, php-version, database server/tables/columns etc) that's different from before and we don't know _anything_ about those parts.

Comment: Ok can you confirm since its been several years, are you sure there is data where you are pulling from?

Comment: Yes I was working

Comment: Please Check I have add a Image Which i am error on Page.

Comment: It's complaining about the SQL query. Do a `var_dump($MySQL);` and post what the final query looks like. It's most likely because you're passing in a negative value as the first value (the offset) for `LIMIT`. It looks like it's `LIMIT -15, 15` in the query (based on the error message). Since you can't have negative amount of records, the offset can't be negative either.